error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op while trying to quantize a model
I am trying to learn about quantization so was playing with a github repo trying to quantize it into int8 format. I have used the following code to quantize the model.
modelClass = DTLN_model()
modelClass.build_DTLN_model(norm_stft=False)
modelClass.model.load_weights(model_path)

# tf.saved_model.save(modelClass.model, output_dir)

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(modelClass.model)
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, 
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS
]

converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]
converter.representative_dataset = lambda: generate_representative_data(num_samples)

tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('saved_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)


And for the representative data, I have converted the data into numpy, saved them as .npy and then used the following code to use them as representative data.
But after I run the code I get the following error:
error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
error: failed while converting: 'main': 
Some ops are not supported by the native TFLite runtime, you can enable TF kernels fallback using TF Select. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select 
TF Select ops: Angle, Exp, IRFFT, TensorListReserve, TensorListSetItem, TensorListStack
Details:
        tf.Angle(tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>) -> (tensor<?x?x257xf32>) : {device = ""}
        tf.Exp(tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>) -> (tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>) : {device = ""}
        tf.IRFFT(tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>, tensor<1xi32>) -> (tensor<?x?x512xf32>) : {device = ""}
        tf.TensorListReserve(tensor<2xi32>, tensor<i32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>) : {device = ""}
        tf.TensorListSetItem(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<?x128xf32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>) : {device = "", resize_if_index_out_of_bounds = false}
        tf.TensorListStack(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<?x?x128xf32>) : {device = "", num_elements = -1 : i64}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py", line 50, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1139, in wrapper
    return self._convert_and_export_metrics(convert_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1093, in _convert_and_export_metrics
    result = convert_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1601, in convert
    saved_model_convert_result = self._convert_as_saved_model()
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1582, in _convert_as_saved_model
    return super(TFLiteKerasModelConverterV2, self).convert(
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1371, in convert
    result = _convert_graphdef(
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 212, in wrapper
    raise converter_error from None  # Re-throws the exception.
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 984, in convert_graphdef
    data = convert(
  File "/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/integration_test/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert.py", line 366, in convert
    raise converter_error
tensorflow.lite.python.convert_phase.ConverterError: Could not translate MLIR to FlatBuffer. UNKNOWN: /home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.Angle' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.Exp' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListStack' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListStack' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.IRFFT' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListStack' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListReserve' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListStack' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: called from
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: called from
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: called from
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: called from
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: note: loc(fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall"]): called from
/home/palak/Projects/Personal_Projects/integration/main.py:50:1: note: Error code: ERROR_NEEDS_FLEX_OPS
tflite_model = converter.convert()
^
<unknown>:0: error: failed while converting: 'main': 
Some ops are not supported by the native TFLite runtime, you can enable TF kernels fallback using TF Select. See instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select 
TF Select ops: Angle, Exp, IRFFT, TensorListReserve, TensorListSetItem, TensorListStack
Details:
        tf.Angle(tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>) -> (tensor<?x?x257xf32>) : {device = ""}
        tf.Exp(tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>) -> (tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>) : {device = ""}
        tf.IRFFT(tensor<?x?x257xcomplex<f32>>, tensor<1xi32>) -> (tensor<?x?x512xf32>) : {device = ""}
        tf.TensorListReserve(tensor<2xi32>, tensor<i32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>) : {device = ""}
        tf.TensorListSetItem(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<?x128xf32>) -> (tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>) : {device = "", resize_if_index_out_of_bounds = false}
        tf.TensorListStack(tensor<!tf_type.variant<tensor<?x128xf32>>>, tensor<2xi32>) -> (tensor<?x?x128xf32>) : {device = "", num_elements = -1 : i64}


I think the main issue is this error: error: 'tf.TensorListSetItem' op is neither a custom op nor a flex op
I have tried to follow the doc https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select and some github issues like https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34350#issuecomment-579027135 and also went through a similar question Issue with tf.ParseExampleV2 when converting to Tensorflow Lite : "op is neither a custom op nor a flex op"
But none of those seemed to be helpful in my case.
Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.
